# Identify unused or duplicate app registrations

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

In SharePoint Online, Apps/Add-in registered on site can be accessed with below link. Please replace tenantname & sitename with your details.

```
https://<tenanatname>.sharepoint.com/sites/<sitename>/_layouts/15/appprincipals.aspx?Scope=Site
```

Currently I don't see an option for unused/invalid app and other audit details like created date, created by, modified by, modified date etc.

Is there any script or particular page where these details can be accessed and where I can clean up the unnecessary ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another wonderful solution to identify the expired,expiring and other useful features built by Patterns and Practices team.

Solution is named as **Tenant Information Portal**

Source code and solution setup steps are available in github from following linnk: https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Tools/tree/master/Solutions/Tenant%20Information%20Portal

Comment: Don't forget to accept one of the answers if it adequately solved your problem!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can view all your registered principal by running below powershell (to run you need to install azure ad powershell module):

```
Connect-MsolService

$applist = Get-MsolServicePrincipal -all | Where-Object -FilterScript { ($_.DisplayName -notlike "*Microsoft*") -and ($_.DisplayName -notlike "autohost*") -and  ($_.ServicePrincipalNames -notlike "*localhost*") }

foreach ($appentry in $applist)
{
    $principalId = $appentry.AppPrincipalId
    $principalName = $appentry.DisplayName

    Get-MsolServicePrincipalCredential -AppPrincipalId $principalId -ReturnKeyValues $false | Where-Object { ($_.Type -ne "Other") -and ($_.Type -ne "Asymmetric") }

     $date = get-date
     Write-Host "$principalName;$principalId;$appentry.KeyId;$appentry.type;$date;$appentry.Usage"

}
```

If you want to remove any particula AppPrincipal, you can use [Remove-MsolServicePrincipal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/msonline/v1/remove-msolserviceprincipal)

More info and code samples here - [Replace an expiring client secret in a SharePoint Add-in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn726681.aspx)